# Declaring Multiple Variables in a For Loop Then assigning those Variable Data

Tags: c++, qt, variables, pointers

I am not sure how to handle this, whether it is a pointer or not.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  
{  
    QString companyTaskText = "companyTask" + QString::number(i + 1);  
    QTextEdit *companyTaskText = new QTextEdit();  
    compoanyTaskText = "companyNumSoldiers" + QString::number(i + 1);  
    QComboBox *companyTaskText = new QComboBox();  
    for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)  
    {  
        ____->addItem(QString::number(i + 1));  
    }  
}
```

So where I am lost is how to point to the QComboBox that was created above in the for loop. I may be just going about this all wrong.

Comment: QComboBox *companyTaskText = new QComboBox();   should be QComboBox *companyTaskCombo = new QComboBox();   and then the confusion is gone.  Just do companyTaskCombo ->addItem(QString::number(i + 1));  in the combo box...

Comment: You **cannot** have multiple variables with the same name declared in the same scope.

Comment: I feel that downvoting this question is somewhat unfair.  It's an elementary question, to be sure, but everybody starts programming someplace.

Comment: Thank you. I have never had any formal education, I've only been learning through examples, google, tutorials, and asking questions.

Comment: Question for the more senior members here: Is there a tag for something like basic-coding-concepts?  It would be a fuzzy line, but this sort of question/answer would still be useful for beginning developers.

Comment: I edited the tag to include basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two different variables using the same name within the same scope, replace the second and third ones (change `companyTaskText` to `companyTaskCombo`/`companyTaskString`).

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  
{  
    QString companyTaskString = "companyTask" + QString::number(i + 1);  
    QTextEdit *companyTaskText = new QTextEdit();  
    companyTaskString = "companyNumSoldiers" + QString::number(i + 1);  
    QComboBox *companyTaskCombo = new QComboBox();  
    for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)  
    {  
        companyTaskCombo->addItem(QString::number(i + 1));  
    }
}
```

Comment: @NathanOlivier: Fixed that

Comment: The `QTextEdit` still has the same name as the `QString`.

Comment: @aschepler: Missed the second one. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure this is going to work. I need to create 5 different ComboBox's for what I am doing that can be seperately identified. This is why I was trying to create a QComboBox using the string created above it.

Comment: If you do `new QComboBox` within a loop doing 5 iterations, you'll definitely get 5 combo box created!

Comment: Alright, but when I need to call information from them, unless I am missing something, all 5 would have the same name?! being `companyTaskCombo` it wouldn't be defined as anything else. If I am not mistaken.

Comment: Why not call `companyTaskCombo->setObjectName( companyTaskString )`? Then each combo-box's object name will be different. But this looks like a different question than the one originally posted.

Comment: That is another way of doing it. That will work, thank you. I did not know or think to look for that function.

Comment: There's still issues here, a bunch of objects are leaked and unused

Comment: @M.M: Sure there are, but it's not obvious to figure out what the OP owner was trying to do...